# Solr - Match whole word only in text fields

Tags: solr, exact-match

I have a text field that can contain very long values (like text files).
I want to create field type for it (text, not string), in order to have something like "Match whole word only" in notepad++, but the delimiter should not be only white spaces.
If i have:

myName=aaa bbb

I would like to get it for the following search strings "aaa", "bbb", "aaa bbb", "myName=aaa bbb", "myName", but not for "aa" or "ame=a" or "a bb".
Another example is:

```
<myName>aaa bbb</myName>
```

Can i do this somehow?

What should be my field type definition?

[EDIT] the text can contain any character. Before search i'm escaping the search string using http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start with, (why do you need to escape special chars? , you need let them get tokenized on them both at index and query time)  :

```
<!-- A general text field that has reasonable, generic
         cross-language defaults: it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer,
     removes stop words from case-insensitive "stopwords.txt"
     (empty by default), and down cases.  At query time only, it
     also applies synonyms. -->
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

This is a good place to learn how your text gets processed both at index and query time.  Very useful admin tool : `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/analysis`

Comment: thx. But that's find aaa only in docs like "name = aaa", but not in docs without space like "name=aaa". I need to find aaa in both.

Comment: Post your full solr query for the example you think it does not work.